# Missing entries in Python heatmap

Tags: matplotlib, scipy, heatmap

I'm hoping someone can shed some light on what I'm doing wrong. I have a heatmap, 182 x 794 entries, however, the final plot is truncating the x-labels despite showing some (or all, it's hard to tell), point values in the plot.

This is the plot:

[image]

And this is my code. To run with the data see the links at the bottom of the post.

```
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram, linkage
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec

linked = linkage(hmapNP,'single')

figure= plt.figure(figsize=(50,50))
gs1 = gridspec.GridSpec(2,7)
gs1.update(wspace=0.01)
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs1[0:-1, :2])
dendrogram(linked, orientation='left', distance_sort='descending',show_leaf_counts=True,no_labels=True)
ax1.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax1.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax1.spines['right'].set_visible(False)

ax2 = plt.subplot(gs1[0:-1,2:6])
f = ax2.imshow(hmapNP, cmap='PRGn_r', interpolation='nearest')

ax2.set_title('Fingerprint Similarity',fontsize=20,weight='bold')
ax2.set_xticks(range(len(meaNameTrueList)))
ax2.set_yticks(range(len(drugNameTrueFinalList)))
ax2.set_xticklabels(meaNameTrueList,rotation=90,size=6)
ax2.set_yticklabels(drugNameTrueFinalList,rotation=45,size=6)

ax3 = plt.subplot(gs1[0:-1,6:7])
m=plt.colorbar(f,cax=ax3,shrink=0.75,orientation='vertical',spacing='uniform',pad=0.01)
m.set_label('Fingerprint Similarity')

plt.tick_params('both',width=2)
plt.plot()
```

The `hmapNP` variable is (182, 794) in shape and looks like:

```
array([[0.05633803, 0.0610687 , 0.06289308, ..., 0.06024096, 0.04411765,
        0.06134969],
       [0.03947368, 0.07936508, 0.08888889, ..., 0.06060606, 0.05970149,
        0.0625    ],
       [0.2       , 0.18055556, 0.08490566, ..., 0.17307692, 0.17333333,
        0.10185185],
       ...,
       [0.0625    , 0.05970149, 0.075     , ..., 0.0591716 , 0.04316547,
        0.06024096],
       [0.08333333, 0.12048193, 0.07894737, ..., 0.09243697, 0.07865169,
        0.13392857],
       [0.07070707, 0.07954545, 0.06837607, ..., 0.06451613, 0.08888889,
        0.08403361]])
```

For this code to run, I've binary pickled and the three variables available to download:

[meaNameTrueList](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16t_r2b0PqtfilcMZwX_gon_gF3TwI_4E/view?usp=sharing)

[hmapNP](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jTHCVO_FQQuyGkGNJVgToSVBNXX5OgjT/view?usp=sharing)

[drugNameTrueFinalList](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qOwgd1moopIXEwmwyWaIRHpzgxSSvtrc/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Maybe you want to transpose the data for the heatmap? `ax2.imshow(hmapNP.T, ...)`?

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick. If you want to move that into an answer I will happily check it off.

Comment: I don't think such answer will help a lot of other people with the same problem, as they won't find this question. Better just delete the question.